# Pandas - Counting values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe with info about the athletes who have participated over the years. I need to determine the proportion of athletes that have participated in both Winter and Summer games.

The dataframe is something like this:

`ID, Name, Sex, Age, Height, Weight, Games, Year, Season, City`

Each `ID` number represents an athlete and in the column `Season` you have either `Winter` or `Summer`. I think I need to find the way to count the `ID`s that have `Winter` and `Summer` and divide it by the total amount of athletes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post examples of your data and your coding attempts.

Comment: The first line for example:

ID: 1
Name: A Dijiang
Games: 1992 Summer
Year: 1992
Season: Summer
City: Barcelona

Comment: I have to count how many athletes have at least participated one time in the Summer games and also in the Winter games.

I thougt about using value_counts() but I dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_both = df.groupby(['ID','Season'])['ID'].count().unstack().fillna(0)
print (len(df_both.loc[(df_both['Summer'] > 0) & (df_both['Winter'] > 0)]) / len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
ID,Season
A,Winter
A,Summer
B,Summer
C,Winter
C,Summer
D,Summer
E,Winter
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')
df=df.groupby('ID')['Season'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
print(df.loc[(df['Summer'] >0) & (df['Winter'] >0)])
```

Result : Just Id A and C have participated in both Winter and Summer games.

```
Season  Summer  Winter
ID                    
A          1.0     1.0
C          1.0     1.0
```